# Css opacity applied to a part of a .png

Tags: wordpress, css, png, opacity

I am working with Wordpress and the piano black theme available as a demo on [pianoblackdemo.wordpress.com](http://pianoblackdemo.wordpress.com).

This theme contains a background that I changed, resulting in the bottom and content (middle) area to need more opacity to make the text readable.

**The middle content uses a png named "side":**

https://pianoblackdemo.wordpress.com/wp-content/themes/pub/piano-black/img/side.png

**The bottom uses another png named "bottom":**

https://pianoblackdemo.wordpress.com/wp-content/themes/pub/piano-black/img/bottom.png

In order to increase opacity on those areas, I applied a rgba() background color on top of those `.png`.

The exact problem is that with this method, it fills the left and right border which is a 4 pixel gradient grey, resulting in an ugly rendering.
In the bottom part, it fills the empty parts on the bottom right and bottom left.

As for the middle part : Is there a way to apply rgba() while ignoring the left and right gradient borders ?

As for the bottom part : I think a way would be to apply a `rgba` to only the first top half of the bottom image (while still ignoring the right and left gradient sides), but I don't know how to do it either.

I tried to edit the images opacity on Gimp, without succeeding. Opacity is already at 100%.

To apply opacity on those `.png` here's what I've done:

```
#middle-contents {
background:url(img/side.png);
repeat-y;
padding-bottom:5px; 
background-color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.90); 
}
```

As for the bottom `.png`, the code is :

```
#footer {
background:url(img/bottom.png) no-repeat top;
height:114px;
margin-bottom:50px; 
}
```

Thank you for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: You cannot affect the opacity of a background image with CSS...nor any specific part of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS solution to achieve that. You might want to open the picture using Photoshop and modify it to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little trick and run the background image on a psudo element. Like this;

HTML

```
<div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus urna nisi, aliquet a lacinia sit amet, interdum vitae magna. Aliquam non velit tempus, consectetur arcu malesuada, placerat risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
   width: 50%;
}
.content:after {
      content:"";
      width: 50%;
      height: 300px;
      background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/);
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      z-index:-1;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/bajere/pen/avLZKq

Will require a lot of playing with though, to line it all up